# Como pasar objetos por queryString Angular

Tags: javascript, java, angular, typescript, frontend

Nesito pasar como parametro de busqueda un objeto con este formato

**fecha: {"inicio": "2021-09-01","fin": "2021-09-01"}**

a una api para realizar una busqueda por fechas.
Pero no encuentro la manera de poder pasar el objeto de este modo para obtener los resultados.

Comment: no depende de que necesites enviar, depende de que recibe el API y como lo recibe, para request de tipo GET, usualmente todo va en la URL y no se pueden enviar objetos, se envían parámetros de búsqueda de forma primitiva como `fecha_inicio=...&fecha_fin=...`.  Siempre puedes intentar cosas como `encodeURIComponent( JSON.stringify(tuObjeto)))` pero puede no resultar, como digo la parte importante aquí es como el API funciona, como recibe los parámetros

Comment: Claro, entiendo a lo que te referis. El problema en este caso es que no se me da informacion de lo que espera recibir el API, solo la informacion que debo enviar para hacer la consulta. De todos, modos muchas gracias por la resupuesta!

Comment: si no es tu API tienes que pedir las especificaciones del endpoint en particular que necesites usar o ya de todo el API pero sin la documentación del API no se puede hacer nada

Answer (score 0):

Debes pasar ese objeto a base 64 y asi lo puedes enviar en la URL facilmente

```
http://localhost/hola?parametro=eyJpbmljaW8iOiAiMjAyMS0wOS0wMSIsImZpbiI6ICIyMDIxLTA5LTAxIn0
```

Aunque, es bueno tener en cuenta que algunos caracteres del base 64 podrian necesitar ser traducidos, pero esto creo que ya angular lo hace, es solo por si armas la cadena de texto "a mano"

ver:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Si tuvieras problema por la cantidad de caracteres que te acepta la url, eso puede resolverse por `webconfig` con

```
<requestLimits maxUrl="65535" maxQueryString="32768" />
```

Comment: Te recomiendo leer el artículo [Te pueden votar negativamente porque tu respuesta resuelve un problema pero agrega otro](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5671/342), esto debido a que hay una cantidad máxima de caracteres que puedes mandar en la URL y que pasar valores por la url puede introducir vulnerabilidades de seguridad. Yo te recomiendo en su lugar intentar cosas como `@Input` y `@Output` si hay herencia entre componentes o usar un servicio para compartir el estado

Comment: @ruslan-lópez Te entiendo, una opción fácil sería recomendar el cambio de método argumentando que no es buena práctica, pero pienso que dar la solución a la pregunta también es importante. Yo personalmente me topé con este problema (enviar objetos por URL), y asi lo resolví.... y lo del tamaño puede resolverse por webconfig con   <requestLimits maxUrl="65535" maxQueryString="32768" />.  (hay que ver cada caso). Mi caso particular se debia a una url externa que llegaba desde un correo, enviaba unos datos y un token encriptado de validación de esa data